# Add Dropdown to infragistics WebDataGrid in Edit mode

Tags: infragistics, webdatagrid

I have two issues:

1. I have a complex object with Id and Text underneath. For display, I am using TemplateDataField with eval function. Can I bind the complex object to a BoundDataField?
2. The reason behind binding the complex object to BoundDataField is, I need to make it editable grid. I could not find any documentation or samples which uses Template field, and make that column editable. (I agree it might not be possible.) Now I need to put a dropdown, where user selects a value and I can assign it to the id field of my complex object. I am able to put a dropdown (using EditorProviders) to a bounddatafield, but how can I do it for the template data field described above?

Here is a link to the samples of Editing WebDatagrid: [Controls & Application Samples](http://www.infragistics.com/products/aspnet/sample/data-grid/editing-editor-providers)

Answer (score 0):

When using a TemplateDataField you are specifying what you want to use as the template and you can put an editor in that Field.  Note that if you do put an editor in that field, you need to handle updates to the grid's value or list that your grid is bound to.

Note that if the values in your drop down have an id associated with them and that can be the value of the grid cell it would be better to use the DropDownEditorProvider with the grid having a bound field where that field is the id of the item that you are selecting.